# uWSGI - log-date with milliseconds

Tags: date, logging, uwsgi

I want to log file to display date as `%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%3N`.

```
$ date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%3N'
Mon Aug 27 12:15:36.954
```

I already found that because of a collision I needed to set `log-date = %%a %%b %%d %%H:%%M:%%S`.

But can't get the milliseconds nor nanoseconds to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strftime()` does not support milliseconds nor nanoseconds.

You have to rely on lower-level systems:

[uWSGI LogFormat](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html)

Unfortunately this requires **uWSGI v1.3+**.

Comment: Thanks, version 1.3 is the way to go about my issue.